# how to resolve read.fwf run time error: invalid multibyte string in R

Tags: r

I'm getting the following when I try to read in a fixed width text file using read.fwf.

Here is the output:
 invalid multibyte string at 'ETE<52>   O       19950207    19031103    537014290   7950 WILLOWS RD

Here are the most relevant lines of code

```
fieldWidths <- c(10,50,30,40,6,8,8,9,35,30,9,2)
colNames <- c("certNum", "lastN", "firstN", "middleN", "suffix", "daDeath", "daBirth", "namesSSN", "namesResStr", "namesResCity", "namesResZip", "namesStCode")
dmhpNameDF <- read.fwf(fileName, widths = fieldWidths, col.names=colNames, sep="", comment.char="", quote="", fileEncoding="WINDOWS-1258", encoding="WINDOWS-1258")
```

I'm running R 3.1.1 on Mac OSX 10.9.4

As you can see, I've experimented with specifying alternative encodings, I've tried latin1 and UTF-8 as well as WINDOWS-1250 through 1258

When I read this file into Excel or Word, or TextEdit everything looks good in general. By using the error message text I can id the offending line (row) of text is row number 5496, and upon inspection, I can see that the offending character shows up as an italic looking letter 'f' Searching for that character reveals that there are about 4 instances of it in this file. I have many such files to process so going through one by one to delete the offending character is not a good solution.

So far, the offending character always shows up in a name field, which is good for me as I don't actually want the name data from this file it is of no interest. If it were a numeric field that was corrupted then I'd have to toss out the row.

Since Word and Excel can read the file (apparently substituting the offending character for italic 'f', surely there must be a way to read it in with R, but I've not figured out a solution. I have searched through the many examples of questions related to "invalid multibyte string", but have not found any info that resolved my problem.

My goal is to be able to read in the data either ignoring this "character error" or substituting the offending character with something else.

Unfortunately the file in question contains sensitive information so I can not post a copy of it for people to play with.

Thanks

Comment: Did you always change both 'fileEncoding' and 'encoding'? I would think just the former is the only only that needs adjusting. Can you extract just that line and read it with `scan`? Is the problem unique to `read.fwf`?

Comment: you can run iconv on it to convert lines to ascii, with the translit option (which will replace offending characters), but to do this you need to first determine the encoding. I found this: http://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding

Comment: I tried changing 'fileEncoding' and 'encoding' independently as well, no difference. I can successfully read the file with 'readLines', but then I would have to go and parse the whole thing and convert all of the text to fields etc, just what read.fwf is meant to do.

Comment: I guess i'm still confused also about the whole encoding issue. It seems to me that this file is not encoded in any obscure format, 99% of it reads in just fine, there seem to be a few characters in there that are funky. Am I missing the point on that?